# Img MatIterator<T> of column exception

Tags: c++, opencv, iterator

I would like to use some STL algorithms for my openCV app. Right now, I would like to mirror the img. I want to reverse the order of rows, columns and both rows an columns. When I type:

```cpp
    // Horizontal and vertical mirror
    MatIterator_<cv::Vec3b> it  = img.begin<cv::Vec3b>();
    MatIterator_<cv::Vec3b> end = img.end<cv::Vec3b>();

    std::reverse(it, end);
```

It works like a charm.

But when I try to iterate through single column or row

```cpp
    MatIterator_<cv::Vec3b> it  = img.col(0).begin<cv::Vec3b>();
    MatIterator_<cv::Vec3b> end = img.col(0).end<cv::Vec3b>();

    std::reverse(it, end);
```

I get an exception from invoking the std::reverse:

```cpp
OpenCV(4.1.1) Error: Assertion failed (i >= 0) in cv::MatSize::operator [], file C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc14\opencv\modules\core\include\opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp, line 1465
OpenCV(4.1.1) C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc14\opencv\modules\core\include\opencv2/core/mat.inl.hpp:1465: error: (-215:Assertion failed) i >= 0 in function 'cv::MatSize::operator []'
```

Mat::col(int number) returns the Mat obj. with the dimensions of [img height x 1], so why get I such an error? The same happens with Mat::row...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are dealing with a dangling reference problem, from the [documentation of `row()`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#acce30f9c4475038ee86ea8b24e00850a) which is referenced by `col()`

> Creates a matrix header for the specified matrix row.
>
> The method makes a **new header for the specified matrix row** and returns
>   it.

The docs stress the fact that that `col()` or `row()` share the data with the original matrix, so there's no copy of the buffer, but you still need your `Mat`object object to know other information, for example the dimensions. Stepping through the problem with the debugger I can see that it crashes because the dimensions of the matrix it points to are `0`. The matrix it points to is the one returned by `col()` that has stopped existing after your first line. You can fix your code making sure that the column matrix survives until it is needed no more:

```
auto col = img.col(0);
cv::MatIterator_<cv::Vec3b> it = col.begin<cv::Vec3b>();
cv::MatIterator_<cv::Vec3b> end = col.end<cv::Vec3b>();
std::reverse(it, end);
```